# Distorted `Tailwind's Component` when importing on React

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm new to Tailwind and I'm facing a issue while importing a component to my react app
The component I'm trying to import is this one [E-Commerce(first one)](https://tailwindui.com/components/ecommerce/components/store-navigation)

I have pasted it in a `Navigation.jsx` file and have imported it in my `App.js` something like this

```
import './App.css';
import Navigation from './Customer/Components/Navigation/Navigation'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="">
      <Navigation />
      <div>Home</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is how my `tailwind.config.js` looks like

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
  ],
}
```

There's nothing more stylings added as of now still I'm getting this weird distorted format.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBbEQ.png)

I have tried adjusting the aspect ratio but it does not work. Maybe a very minor thing I'm missing

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have also included `jsx` in `tailwind.config.js`. It would be something like this:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [ 
        // include `jsx` as well.
        "./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx}",
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [
        require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
    ],
}
```

Hope this answer helps.